# How to make a Toast through the Media_Button?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I need only simple functionally:

When I click the Media Button (Like Volume up/down), I need to print a Toast that `Volume button is pressed`

I Declared the receiver in the manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It does not work for me. Please suggest me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture Key Events to achieve this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use KeyEvent. See this for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html